# VHDL type conversion for array of arrays in neural network

Tags: initialization, neural-network, type-conversion, vhdl

I'm working with a feed forward neural network developed by David Aledo (See OpenCores project [Artificial Neural Network (ANN)](http://opencores.org/project,artificial_neural_network)) and I am having trouble with initializing RAM arrays in instances generated by the code.

The code generates layers of the neural network as instances. Each of these instances has block RAM associated with a layer weight matrix. This RAM is represented in the code as an array of arrays of std_logic_vector as shown below:

```
type ramd_type is array (NumN-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW -1 downto 0);
type layer_ram is array (NumIn-1 downto 0) of ramd_type;
```

where `NumN` and `NumIN` are layer-dependent and `NbitW` is constant.

What I want to do is to initialize this RAM with a constant. To do this I've created a package containing the following:

```
type ramd_type0 is array (33 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);
type layer_ram0 is array (26 downto 0) of ramd_type0;
type ramd_type1 is array (4  downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);
type layer_ram1 is array (33 downto 0) of ramd_type1;
type ramd_type2 is array (0  downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);
type layer_ram2 is array (4  downto 0) of ramd_type2;

constant w0 : layer_ram0 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
constant w1 : layer_ram1 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
constant w2 : layer_ram2 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
```

Inside the layer Entities I've declared functions which select the constant apropriate to the layer number generic `Lnum`:

```
function w_init(LNum : natural) return layer_ram is
begin
  if LNum = 0 then
    return layer_ram(w0);
  elsif LNum = 1 then
    return layer_ram(w1);
  elsif LNum = 2 then
    return layer_ram(w2);
  else
    return layer_ram(w2);
  end if;
end w_init;
```

Where `layer_ram` is defined like above.

When analyzing with GHDL I get the following error:

> conversion not allowed between not closely related types

In Modelsim I get this one:

> Illegal type conversion from work.wb_init.layer_ram0 to layer_ram (array element type difference).

I get that the problem is that according to the simulators the `layer_ram` and `layer_ram0` are not closely related and it's because the array elements have different types `ramd` and `ramd0`. For me this seems to be against the 1993 standard which states that array types are closely related when:

> -- For each index position, the index types are either the same or are closely related;

Am I right? How could I initialize these arrays with constants without changing the layer_ram type into an array of std_logic_vectors?

---

edit:

A minimal working example that reproduces my problem can be viewed here: https://gist.github.com/jstefanowicz/e4f43a822cf5dd46c2668bfffa33c66c

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library work;
package wb_init is

    constant NbitW : natural := 18;

    type ramd_type0 is array (1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);
    type ramd_type1 is array (2  downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);

    type layer_ram0 is array (3 downto 0) of ramd_type0;
    type layer_ram1 is array (4 downto 0) of ramd_type1;

    constant w0 : layer_ram0 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));
    constant w1 : layer_ram1 := (others => (others => (others => '0')));

end wb_init ;

--- test_gen:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.wb_init.all;

entity test_gen is

   generic
   (
      LNum    : natural ;  
      NumN    : natural := 8; 
      NumIn   : natural := 8   
   );

   port
   (
      inputs  : in std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);
      outputs : out std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0) 
   );

end test_gen;

architecture beh of test_gen is

  type ramd_type is array (NumN-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0); 
  type layer_ram is array (NumIn-1 downto 0) of ramd_type;

  function w_init(LNum : natural) return layer_ram is
  begin
   if LNum = 0 then
     return layer_ram(w0);
   elsif LNum = 1 then
     return layer_ram(w1);
   else
     return layer_ram(w1);
   end if;
  end w_init;

  signal lram  : layer_ram := w_init(LNum); 

begin
  outputs<= inputs;
end beh;

--- test_gen_tb:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.wb_init.all;

entity test_gen_tb is
end test_gen_tb;

architecture beh of test_gen_tb is

component test_gen is
  generic
  (
     LNum    : natural := 0; 
     NumN    : natural := 64;
     NumIn   : natural := 8  
  );

  port
  (
     inputs  : in std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);
     outputs : out std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0) 
  );

  end component;
  type gen_ar is array (1 downto 0) of natural;
  signal NumN_ar : gen_ar := (2,3);
  signal NumIn_ar : gen_ar := (4,5);
  signal inputs,outputs : std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);


begin

  test_gen_inst:
  for i in 0 to 1 generate
  test_gen
  generic map (
    LNum  => i,
    NumN  => NumN_ar(i),
    NumIn => NumIn_ar(i)
  )
  port map (
    inputs  => inputs,
    outputs => outputs
  );  
  end generate;

end beh;
```

Comment: The issue is that the element types are different, one has an element type of ramd_type and the other an element type of ramd_type0, both array types. You don't show the value of constant NumN. Without more information (a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) it isn't clear what the corrective action would be. Note also the dimensionality of w0, w1, and w2 are different. Your w_init function likely wants to be three functions or you're simply doing something procedurally wrong.

Comment: NumN is not a constant but a generic. The function returns different array sizes depending on the generic LNum. When LNum = 0 then NumN and NumIn is equal to the w0 dimensions and so on. The whole point is that I would like to initialize the array of arrays that can have different dimensions depending on the generic values.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.1 *A generic interface list consists entirely of interface constant declarations, interface type declarations, interface subprogram declarations, and interface package declarations.*   NumN` is an interface constant, the reserved word constant is optional (6.5.2). Will your tool chain support interface type declarations (6.5.3)?

Comment: Alternatively because these don't show up on the entity interface list use only local declarations and make them consistently dependent on generic constants.

Comment: I'm afraid that my tool chain won't go with the types passed through the interface. As for the other option, I've tried locally declared constants with the weight matrices, but the problem with that is the following. If I declare w0 as a 3x3 array and w1 as 5x3 array both with type layer_ram (array dimensions dependent on generics) then I get bound check failures during compilation. I also tried to pass the weight matrix agregates directly to the return values of the function w_gen (with a type conversion) but I got and error saying agregates can't be type conversion operands.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to initialize the array of arrays by assigning it element by element in the function `winit`. Here is a fix for the minimal example posted above: (https://gist.github.com/jstefanowicz/abad35de9b0a930033e54ed0deeed771)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library work;
package wb_init is

    constant NbitW : natural := 18;

    type ramd_type0 is array (1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);
    type ramd_type1 is array (2  downto 0) of std_logic_vector(NbitW-1 downto 0);

    type layer_ram0 is array (3 downto 0) of ramd_type0;
    type layer_ram1 is array (4 downto 0) of ramd_type1;

    constant w0 : layer_ram0 := (others => (others =>(others =>'0')));
    constant w1 : layer_ram1 := (others => (others =>(others =>'0')));

end wb_init ;

--- test_gen:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.wb_init.all;

entity test_gen is

   generic
   (
      LNum    : natural ;  
      NumN    : natural ; 
      NumIn   : natural    
   );

   port
   (
      inputs  : in std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
      outputs : out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0) 
   );

end test_gen;

architecture beh of test_gen is


  type ramd_type is array (NumN-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(17 downto 0); 
  type layer_ram is array (NumIn-1 downto 0) of ramd_type;


  function w_init(LNum : natural) return layer_ram is
    variable tmp_arr : layer_ram ;
  begin
    if LNum = 0 then
      for i in 0 to NumIn-1 loop
        for j in 0 to NumN-1 loop
           tmp_arr(i)(j) := w0(i)(j);
        end loop;
     end loop;
    elsif LNum = 1 then
      for i in 0 to NumIn-1 loop
        for j in 0 to NumN-1 loop
           tmp_arr(i)(j) := w1(i)(j);
        end loop;
      end loop;
    else
      for i in 0 to NumIn-1 loop
        for j in 0 to NumN-1 loop
           tmp_arr(i)(j) := (others => '0');
        end loop;
      end loop;
    end if;

    return tmp_arr ;
  end w_init;

  signal lram  : layer_ram := w_init(LNum); 

begin
  outputs<= inputs;
end beh;

--- test_gen_tb:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

--library work;
--use work.wb_init.all;

entity test_gen_tb is
end test_gen_tb;

architecture beh of test_gen_tb is

component test_gen is
  generic
  (
     LNum    : natural ; 
     NumN    : natural ;
     NumIn   : natural   
  );

  port
  (
     inputs  : in std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
     outputs : out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0) 
  );

  end component;
  type gen_ar is array (1 downto 0) of natural;
  signal NumN_ar : gen_ar := (3,2);
  signal NumIn_ar : gen_ar := (5,4);
  signal inputs,outputs : std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);

begin

  test_gen_inst:
  for i in 0 to 1 generate
  tg:test_gen
  generic map (
    LNum  => i,
    NumN  => NumN_ar(i),
    NumIn => NumIn_ar(i)
  )
  port map (
    inputs  => inputs,
    outputs => outputs
  );  
  end generate;

end beh;
```